# How to create widget list in python?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, widget

I want to **add buttons** to **list**, I know there is widget list and I already read is somewhere but I forgot where. I **can't find** any helpful posts on this question.

I want to **change** button's **background** in **for loop**, when some action happens, like **mouse hovering**.

I'm using python 3.10.4

Thanks for any **help**!

Comment: There isn't a special widget list. You can create one like you create any list.

Comment: I give up with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step one**: create an empty list

```
widget_list = []
```

**Step two**: add widgets to the list

```
for i in range(10):
    button = tk.Button(root, text=f"Button #{i+1}", command=reset)    
    widget_list.append(button)
```

**Step three**: loop over the list to change the background:

```
for widget in widget_list:
    widget.configure(background="red")
```

If the code in these steps are in separate functions,  you'll need to declare `widget_list` as global variable or an instance variable.

Comment: Ah thanks, then I didn't remember right. I thought threre is a special list for widgets. I'm going to do it with some elifs in for loop

Comment: @GamerTronky: there's a command to get a list of children for a given widget, is that what you're thinking of (eg: `root.winfo_children()`)?

Comment: I think not....

Comment: And I didn't know you can append buttons to list, maybe is that going to solve something!